# Can Windows store apps generate UI Events?

Tags: windows, windows-store-apps, windows-store

I am considering writing a Kinect v2.0 Gesture -> Keyboard/Mouse event translator so I can control video games. Since I will be using Microsoft's SDK, cross-platform is out-of-the-question; it seems natural to distribute this through the Windows store. However, I know Windows store apps have significant restrictions. Can a Windows store app:

1. Run in the background (possibly with an elevated priority to ensure that the game doesn't miss input)?
2. Create user input events like "key-down" and "mouse move" that will be read by other applications?

Looking at [Microsoft's capability page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh464936.aspx) didn't seem to give me a definite yes or no.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to write this as a desktop app. Windows Store apps run in a sandboxed context with limited access to the system. They cannot interact with other processes as you'd need, and they cannot inject input events.

Comment: Right! Sandboxing prevents interaction . Every app has its own sandboxed zone